# htaccess regex to find image and image number

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have such a url:

> /keyword1/keyword2/slugged-title-8286-1.jpg?wx=292&hx=164

I would like to forward in this case to:

> /images/8286-1.jpg?wx=292&hx=164

the listing number (here 8286) can be 4 or 5 digits and could perhaps contain letters. Also the parameters after ? could be different.

Could you please help me to get this solved?
I haven't done a lot with regex and not sure how this can be done.

Comment: Can you add few more examples of original and rewritten URLs? Do you want to do internal rewrite or full redirect?

Comment: You should also show what RegEx you have already attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule -(\w+(?:-\d+)?\.jpe?g)$ /images/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

If you don't want a full redirect then use:

```
RewriteRule -(\w+(?:-\d+)?\.jpe?g)$ /images/$1 [L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to target URL.

Comment: You know .. That's odd for me, people come here and ask their questions, but don't care about the answers ...! I think this solution is exactly what OP wants ... But where is OP? Why he doesn't give you up vote? Why he doesn't mark your answer as accepted one, Why at least he doesn't say you "tnx" ? What's wrong with some people ..!!!

Comment: Because there a people outside they may have a job that requires a lot of traveling and also have a familiy to take care. Since I asked I wasn't back on my office desk. But now, having not tried the suggest solution, as I have to take care about other projects first, I give you the quote to appreciate your answer!